# Mongodb aggregate three collections

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Learning MongoDB for the past two days and I am trying to aggregate three collections but unable to achieve it

Below are the four collection maintaining in the database

**university**

```
{
   "_id" : "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d82",
   "name": "NIFT"
}
```

**college**

```
{
   "_id" : "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d83",
   "name": "NIFT Hyderabad",
   "university_id":"5834ecf7432d92675bde9d82"
}
```

**departments**

```
{
   "_id" : "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d84",
   "department_name": "Fashion Technology",
   "college_id" : "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d83" 
},
{
   "_id" : "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d85",
   "department_name": "Merchandising",
   "college_id" : "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d83"
}
```

**Sections**

```
{
   "_id" : "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d86",
   "section_name": "A",
   "students" : "56",
   "department_id":"5834ecf7432d92675bde9d84"
},
{
   "_id" : "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d87",
   "section_name": "B",
   "students" : "60",
   "department_id":"5834ecf7432d92675bde9d84"
},
{
   "_id" : "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d86",
   "section_name": "A",
   "students" : "55",
   "department_id":"5834ecf7432d92675bde9d85"
},
{
   "_id" : "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d87",
   "section_name": "B",
   "students" : "44",
   "department_id":"5834ecf7432d92675bde9d85"
}
```

Here I am trying to achieve the output in the below format

**Expected Output**

```
[{
   "_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d83",
   "name": "NIFT Hyderabad",
   "university_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d82",
   "departments": [{
        "_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d84",
        "department_name": "CSE",
        "college_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d83",
        "sections": [{
            "_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d86",
            "section_name": "A",
            "students": "56",
            "department_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d84"
        }, {
            "_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d87",
            "section_name": "B",
            "students": "60",
            "department_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d84"
        }]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d85",
        "department_name": "Mechanical",
        "college_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d83",
        "sections": [{
                "_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d86",
                "section_name": "A",
                "students": "55",
                "department_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d85"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d87",
                "section_name": "B",
                "students": "44",
                "department_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d85"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

But, I am getting department and sections in separate arrays for college but not able to get like in the above format

**Query**

```
db.college.aggregate([
            {"$match": { "university_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d82" } },
            {"$lookup": {
            "localField": "_id",
            "from": "departments",
            "foreignField": "college_id",
            "as": "departments"
        }},
        {"$unwind":"$departments"},
        {$group : {_id : "$_id", departments : {$push : "$departments" }}},
        {"$lookup": {
        "localField": "departments._id",
        "from": "sections",
        "foreignField": "department_id",
        "as": "sections"}
        }
        ])
```

Can any one help me to solve this issue, it will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query.

The below query pushes the `sections` into `department` when they are joined and `$group` to push department to create the final structure.

```
db.college.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "university_id": "5834ecf7432d92675bde9d82"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "localField": "_id",
      "from": "departments",
      "foreignField": "college_id",
      "as": "departments"
    }
  },
  {
   "$unwind": {
     "path": "$departments",
     "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "localField": "departments._id",
      "from": "sections",
      "foreignField": "department_id",
      "as": "departments.sections"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      "university_id": {
        "$first": "$university_id"
      },
      "departments": {
        "$push": "$departments"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks @Veeram It works. I am also facing one more issue, there is an entry in college and no departments and section entries for that college, In this case, not able to get that college alone entry in the above query. I able to get only if College has department entries

Comment: {
     "$unwind": { "path": "$departments", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": 
     true }
     },
I have update the unwind to match empty and it works, @Veeram  pls update the same

Thanks for your time, It really helpful and learned new

Comment: what if you want to start from university and not college ?